# Путаница с кавычками при передаче параметров

Tags: javascript, экранирование

Я вызываю функцию `clickEditCampaing` и передаю параметры списком. При наличии кавычек в самом тексте, естественно, происходит ошибка. Если в параметрах есть кавычки, то логика путает кавычки текста с `&quot;` в функции и не может выбрать нужные параметры. Как правильно заэкранировать кавычки в данном случае?

```
<button 
    type='button' 
    class='btn btn-xs' 
    title='Редактировать акцию' 
    onclick='clickEditCampaing("+ campaignId + ", &quot;" + campaignTitle + "&quot;)'
></button>
```

Comment: А вариант написать по-нормальному в JS не рассматриваете? `addEventListener('click', function() {...})`

Comment: @steklishko если ответ решил проблему, ставьте галочу ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button 
  type='button'
  class='btn btn-xs'
  title='Редактировать акцию'
  onclick='clickEditCampaing("\""+ campaignId + "\"", "\"" + campaignTitle + "\"")'>
</button>
```

или

```
<button 
  type='button'
  class='btn btn-xs'
  title='Редактировать акцию'
  onclick='clickEditCampaing("&quot;"+ campaignId + "&quot;", "&quot;" + campaignTitle + "&quot;")'>
</button>
```